# Which table element can be used in Polymer3?

Tags: javascript, npm, polymer-3.x

I found iron-data-table(https://www.webcomponents.org/element/Saulis/iron-data-table)
but it using **bower** like **Polymer2** , I am just using **npm** in **Polymer3**

Is there a table element or an alternative solution for **Polymer3**?

Comment: Convert it, with this upgrade guide. As I did the same if the element owner didn't do it. https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/upgrade . Or, vaadin has `vaadin-grid` element. That you can find their website or npm packages store instead of webcomponent.org as there only Polymer 2 version exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the classic `<table></table>` tags with `dom-repeat` for each row but below is an alternative as well,
https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid
Listing some feature,

**Lazy loading**:
Lazy loading of data from any data source.

**Big Data**:
Easily present and scroll through 100k lines of data in a single UI component.

**Custom headers**:
Combine multiple rows and display components in your grid headers.

**Smooth scrolling**:
Lightning fast and smooth hardware accelerated scrolling by reusing DOM elements.

**Super efficient**:
Super efficient custom renderers for presenting custom data any way you want.

**Expanding row details**:
Show more data under a row in an expandable details row.

**Touch and keyboard**:
Touch event and mobile support, and keyboard navigation.

**Accessible**:
Works with screen readers to ensure all your users are able to use the grid.

**Customizable**:
Vaadin Grid comes with both Lumo and Material design themes, and it can be customized to fit your application.